# How to change iframe src at runtime?

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a problem with IFrame .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370208/i-have-a-problem-with-iframe)

Now i am using iframe.attribute("src")="..Pages/page.aspx"....In Chrome and ie this one is working.....but Firefox not?Can anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try This ..

```
 iframe.attribute("src")="../Pages/page.aspx"
```

Comment: Vibin / Joby -- are you using a shill account?

Answer (score 1):

If you really have "..Pages/Page.aspx" then you are missing a backslash between .. and Pages

```
 iframe.attribute("src")="../Pages/page.aspx"
                           ^^^
```

Comment: how it is working in IE and Chrome, but not in FF