# I have a problem with IFrame 

Tags: asp.net

hai ,

I have an iFrame for display dynamic pages in my page.

```
 <iframe id="divIFrame" scrolling="no" runat ="server"  src="Login.aspx"  frameborder="0"
       style="width: 575px; height:323px; padding:0px;z-index:0px;" >
 </iframe>
```

In the code behind I used one line code to add 'src' attribute to the iframe.

```
 divIFrame.Attributes("src") = "..\Pages\Company.aspx"
```

it's works in IE aand crome but Not in Mozila firefox.It shows an Error Like this

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.
Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 9.0.0.0
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use forward slash / and not backslash \ in your URL.

```
 divIFrame.Attributes("src") = "../Pages/Company.aspx"
```

Internet Explorer is quietly converting the slashes for you, masking a problem. Firefox correctly doesn't.

Comment: I think most people (AFAIK) would call \ backslash and / forward slash. +1 for the comment though

Comment: @Dolbz - you're probably right. I always get confused between the two :) [[editted]]